# Automatically escaping characters within strings

Tags: c#, string, escaping

I am working on a C# project where I am exporting data from a database that is defined by the user so I have no idea what the data is going to contain or the format it is going to be in.

Some of the strings within the database might include apostrophe's (') which I need to escape but everything I've found on the internet shows that I would have to do string.replace("'", "\'"); which seems a bit odd as it would be a mass of replace statements for every possibility.

Isn't there a better way to do this.

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: Escaping for what purpose?

Comment: The strings are being written to a file contained with single quotes e.g. ``'hello'`` if the string contains an apostrophe I need to escape the single quote so the string is not ended before the end of the string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recently had to make a code fix for this same problem. I had to put a ton of string.replace() statements everywhere. My recommendation would be to create a method that handles all escape character possibilities and have your query strings pass through this method before being executed. If you design your structure correctly you should only have to call this method once.

```
    public string FixEscapeCharacterSequence(string query)
    {
        query = query.Replace("'", "\'");
        //..Any other replace statements you need
        //....

        return query;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. Thought there would be a built in function like php.